# L1-Norm Batch Normalization for Efficient Training of Deep Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, batch-normalization

Could anyone help to derive equation (15) dL/dx in [L1-Norm Batch Normalization for Efficient Training of Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09769.pdf#page=3) ?

I found that the term inside the rectangle for the expression (12) is equal to zero.

[image]